# How to decrease the Vagrant package(.box) size?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have created the vagrant box from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit desktop ISO file. The Vagrant box size is more than 1.5 GB.

- How can I reduce the size of Vagrant box?
- How to remove unnecessary files from installed Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Hi SJ. In case you're not aware, the community has discussed the addition of signatures in posts, and has decided it prefers posts without. We tend to think that the profile card serves this purpose, and that it does not need adding again. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use (and modify if needed) some existing [Packer](http://www.packer.io/) template. They normally already have cleaning and disk minimizing implemented.

Anyway, the idea is to remove the unneeded packages and clean up large tmp files, apt cache,  etc. And finally clean up the disk image by writing zeroes to it to make sure it compresses optimally. See for example [this](https://github.com/opscode/bento/blob/82752ec/packer/scripts/ubuntu/cleanup.sh) and [this](https://github.com/opscode/bento/blob/82752ec/packer/scripts/common/minimize.sh) example from the [Bento](https://github.com/opscode/bento) project.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that "Vagrant itself makes no effort to save disk space from VirtualBox. It just calls VBoxManage exportvm" https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/343#issuecomment-39506583